# Is such a partition available?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Consider : 
$$
S = \{1,2,\cdots, N\}
$$
We want to partition $S$ into $K$ parts ($S_1\cup S_2\cup\cdots\cup S_K=S$) to satisfy these equalities :
$$
\sum_{k \in S_d} a_k = \frac1K \sum_{k \in S} a_k\quad, \qquad d=1,2,\cdots,K
$$
where $a_k$'s are positive.

Actually the problem is finding both such a partition(s) and $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^N$ (up to scale!)

It is a part of a big problem that I simplified it to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take any partition of $S$ into $K$ parts (such a thing exists iff $N \ge K$) and let for each $k\in S$ let $i(k)$ be the index with $k \in S_{i(k)}$, then let $a_k := \frac 1{|S_{i(k)}|}$. For each $d$ we then have 
$$ 
\sum_{k \in S_d} a_k = \sum_{k\in S_d} \frac 1{|S_d|} = 1 $$
and hence $\sum_{k\in S} a_k = K = K \cdot \sum_{k\in S_d} a_k$ for each $d$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You know the problem I'm facing is more restricted somehow and considering them would constraint your general solution. Am I allowed to add those constraints? or it is better to ask a new question?